# Magento - Difference between translate.csv and core_translate

Tags: magento, internationalization

What is the difference between `translate.csv` translations and the database method via the table `core_translate`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is part of init() method from app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php

```
//Loading data from module translation files
        foreach ($this->getModulesConfig() as $moduleName=>$info) {
            $info = $info->asArray();
            $this->_loadModuleTranslation($moduleName, $info['files'], $forceReload);
        }
        $this->_loadThemeTranslation($forceReload);
        $this->_loadDbTranslation($forceReload);
```

From it you can see that Magento load translation in the following order, i.e. there are three options in Magento to add a custom translation to a text string: module translation, theme translation and inline translation.

*Module translation*

Module translations are stored in `app/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE/` folder in form of csv files, named as Namespace_Modulename.csv All string in extensions that are inside `__()` method can be translated this way

*Theme translation*

Strings can be translated inside your theme, for that you just need to set locale via Magento admin area, then create translate.csv in `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE` and put your translated strings inside this CSV

```
“My Cart”,”My Basket”

“My Account”,”Account”
```

*Inline translation*

To enable inline translation you need to log into Admin panel and go to `System -> Configuration -> Developer` and then find Translate inlined and set `Enabled` for frontend Yes

All translation made by this method will be stored in core_translate table inside your database. In order to understand better how this method works, [check this video out.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/in_line_translations_magento/)

The text above is [a part of my article on our blog](http://blog.belvg.com/magento-certified-developer-exam-internationalization.html)

Answer (score 5):

core_translate table is for phrases that depends on StoreView

/app/design/frontend/YOUR PACKAGE/YOUR THEME/locale/YOUR LOCALE/translate.csv for phrases in YOUR LOCALE language for YOUR THEME. If you change theme this phrases will not be used (translate.csv from new theme will be used).

If phrase is available in database and in csv, then DB phrase will be used.

Comment: Also, the inline translation feature modifies the `core_translate` table.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, core_translate is useful when you are running magento in a distributed method on multiple servers, and reading from the filesystem just isn't ideal.
I use core_translate with inline translations to handle translated content in CMS blocks. (a mod)
The reason for this is that it is faster to read from the db than to parse a .csv. (I do not know if this is true with caching turned on, but it seemed like the safest route to go)

Answer (score 0):

I dug up this old forum that suggested a few things.  Possibly Magento is trying use the inline core_translate approach and push out the translate.csv.  However given the forum thread is from 2008 that doesn't seem to be the case.  The other suggestion is that some languages use core_translate on the database while some keep the records in a .csv.  Possibly the .csv is for local maintainers and the core_translate is for admins.  Here's the thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40510/