# Magento theme frontend language variables

Tags: magento

I've purchased a Magento theme and installed it, but now I have a mixed language frontend (english/german), where I can set the german variables for output? In the default output all of this is german, but not in the new theme.
E.g.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Quick overview'); ?>
```

If I create a file

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
```

With this input:

```
"Quick overview","Kurzbeschreibung"
```

It doesn't work..

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What you've done is correct but I would have put it into my package/theme directory rather than default/default.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence might be the issue. You might have the translations in database. CHeck out the core_translate table to be sure.

TEXT FROM THIS LINK: [Magento - Difference between translate.csv and core_translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793422/magento-difference-between-translate-csv-and-core-translate)

Magento load translation in the following order, i.e. there are three options in Magento to add a custom translation to a text string: module translation, theme translation and inline translation.

Module translation

Module translations are stored in app/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE/ folder in form of csv files, named as Namespace_Modulename.csv All string in extensions that are inside __() method can be translated this way

Theme translation

Strings can be translated inside your theme, for that you just need to set locale via Magento admin area, then create translate.csv in app/design/frontend///locale/ languagecode_COUNTRYCODE and put your translated strings inside this CSV

“My Cart”,”My Basket”

“My Account”,”Account”

Inline translation

To enable inline translation you need to log into Admin panel and go to System -> Configuration -> Developer and then find Translate inlined and set Enabled for frontend Yes

Answer (score 0):

first change your csv name Test_Testmodule.csv if you have created module Test_Testmodule then your csv file name should be Test_Testmodule.csv

then put it app/locale/de_DE/Test_Testmodule.csv  then refresh cache and check it is translated or not.

Check also have you selected language de_DE in admin panel default language in sytem -> configuration ->general -> locale options.

Answer (score 0):

The Csv file magento uses for inline translation depends on the locale option you have chosen from the admin panel. In your

> System->Configuration->General->Locale options

Here you can select the country.If you have chosen **United States** then magento will look for translate csv in **en_US** folder in your locale folder.

So for example if you have your store locale selected **United States** go to your

> app/locale

folder and inside your en_US folder, make the changes to the particular file that contains the text **Quick overview** and replace it with **Kurzbeschreibung**.

But if you have different language for your whole store than you have to create a new store view.

Hope this will help.